# If you join two tables in the SELECT statement, all indexes on the table columns can no longer be used?

Tags: sql, indexing

Let's say we have:

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM Pictures 
    JOIN Categories ON Categories.CategoryId = Pictures.CategoryId
   WHERE Pictures.UserId = @UserId
ORDER BY Pictures.UploadDate DESC
```

In this case, the database first join the two tables and then work on the derived table, which I think would mean the indexes on the individual tables would be no use, unless you can come up with an index that is bound to some column in the derived table?

Comment: First and foremost, get rid of the "select *" if you're worried about performance. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a fundamental misunderstanding of how SQL works. The SQL language specifies what result set should be returned. It says nothing about how the database should achieve those results.

It is up to the database engine to parse the statement and come up with an execution plan (hopefully an efficient one) that will produce the correct results. Many modern relational databases have sophisticated query optimizers that completely pull apart the statement and derive execution plans that seem to have no relationship with the original query. (At least not to the untrained eye)

The execution plan for the same query can even change over time if the engine uses a cost based optimizer. A cost based optimizer makes decisions based on statistics that have been gathered about data and indexes. As the statistics change, the execution plan can also change.

With your simple query you assume that the database has to join the tables and create a temporary result set before it applies the where clause. That might be how you think about the problem, but the database is free to implement it entirely differently. I doubt there are many (if any) databases that would create a temporary result set for your simple query.

This is not to say that you cannot ever predict when an index may or may not be used. But it takes practice and experience to get a feel for how a database *might* execute a query.

Comment: Hi I get your point, however the column indexes of a database are created by developers, not by the optimizer, which means developers MUST try to predict the excution plan, don't you think?

Comment: Absolutely, a good developer (and/or dba) will strategically create indexes and write queries and other DML for optimal performance. But as I said, it takes practice. There are whole books written about the subject. My answer wasn't intended to discourage you from thinking about it.

Comment: So what do you suggest a junior level developer do when it comes to writing indexes in this scenario in my question?

Answer (score 1):

This will join the tables giving you all the category information if a picture's 'CategoryId' is in the table 'Categories''s CategoryId field. (and no result for a particular 'Picture' if there is no such category)

This query will likely return several rows of data. The indexes of either table will be useful no matter which table you would like to access.

Normally your program would loop through the result set.

CategoryId will give you the row in Categories with all the relevant fields in that Category and 'Picture.Id' (assuming there is such a field) will give you a reference to that exact picture row in the database.

You can then manipulate either table by using the relevant index
"UPDATE Categories SET .... WHERE CategoryId = " + 
"UPDATE Pictures ..... WHERE PictureId =" + 
or some such depending on your programming environment.

Answer (score 0):

Indexes are up to the optimizer for use, which depends on what is occurring in the query.  For the query posted, there's nothing obvious to stop an index from being used.  However, not all databases operate the same -- MySQL only allows one index to be used per SELECT (check the query plan, because the optimizer might interpret the JOIN so that another index may be used).

The stuff that is likely to ensure that an index can not be used is any function/operation that alters the data.  IE: getting the month/etc out of a date, wildcarding the left side of a LIKE clause...

Comment: Hi, you see, an index of the original table would point to a row of the table, but the WHERE and ORDER BY conditions work on the derived joined table, which I guess an index of the original table would be useless in this case?

Comment: @Aperture: What you posted is not a derived table -- a derived table/inline view is generally called a subselect or subquery, a SELECT in a FROM clause.  IE: `FROM (SELECT ...)`.  There's nothing derived in your example.

Comment: In this case, the WHERE and ORDER BY clauses work on the resultant table which is the result of the JOIN action. Since an UserId index only point to rows of the original Pictures table, not the resultant table, I'm guessing the UserId index would not be used by database in this query?

Comment: @Aperture: "resultant table" is the same as derived table/inline view -- again, NO the database does not "stage data" or however you've been implying/believing.  Indexes can be used by the ORDER BY clause, or even the SELECT clause if the optimizer determines the use is possible.

Comment: @Aperture - Even if a query does join to or select from a derived table or view, that doesn't mean the derived table has to be "created" first before the rest of the query can proceed. The optimizer is free to restructure the query into something that looks completely different, as long as it gives the same result.

Comment: @Aperture: What dbenham is referring to is known as "predicate pushing"